# Removing "category.description" block

Tags: magento2, layout, category, magento2.2.6

I'm trying to remove the description block via:

> app/design/vendor/module/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View"
               name="children_category_imgs"
               template="category/children_category_imgs.phtml"
               before="category.products"/>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="category.description" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

> vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
....
</page>
```

[image]

I have sucessfully removed the image using the same method.

Comment: Have you flushed Magento cache after adding code for removing category description?

Comment: Yes, I have flushed Magento Cache, even compiled again.

Answer (score 3):

`app/design/frontend/Company_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="category.description" remove="true"/>
```

Just clean the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: As I say in the problem, I have already done this but it does still not work.